# How the term 'colorless' is defined in physics?

Tags: optics

In english literature,colorless means something having no colour.

Scientifically, what does it mean when we say that something is colorless, is it some other visible wavelength or some mixture of VIBGYOR or something else?

Comment: It depends on context.  In QCD for example, it means no net color charge.

Comment: In ordinary physics use, it means the same things as in English literature. But keep in mind color is not a property of light. Color happens in the mind. See https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/339130/37364

Comment: Usually used in the phrase "colourless liquid" - transparent over the whole visible spectrum.

Comment: See [Exactly which objects should we considered as colorless?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/797177/37364) for an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Color is a perception of the human brain, because of the biological construct of the cones of the retina. It so happens that the [spectrum of light through a crystal](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/vision/specol.html) orders color in a way that it can be given a physics ( not a perception which depends on biology)definition.

[image: prismcolor]

There is a one to one correspondence of the colors we observe with our eyes to the frequency of the light as described in electromagnetic theory.

The [perception of color](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/vision/colper.html) though by our brain can see these colors with combinations of the frequency found through the analysis of the prism.

[image: color perc]