# Can you create white light by combining cyan wavelengths (490-520nm) with red wavelengths (630-700nm)?

Tags: optics, visible-light, wavelength, vision

Cyan (blue light + green light) + red light = white light,

but is the same true for cyan wavelengths ($490-520$ nm) and red wavelengths ($630-700$ nm)?

Comment: Another surprisingly common way to make "white light" from only 2 wavelengths is "lunar white" made from single-frequency blue + single-frequency yellow.

Comment: Should we clarify: "perceived as white" instead of just white? This combo would still appear different than white light, through a prism.

Comment: Something like this? https://youtu.be/7iV1m4j2wJQ

Comment: @Jeffrey - No need. Light has a mix of wavelengths, but does not have color. Color happens in the brain as a result of color receptors being stimulated. Any bright light that stimulates the receptors equally is white because it will be perceived as white.

Comment: Just make it bright enough, then lambdas don't matter

Comment: @Carl If you simply make the cyan and red brighter (increase the intensity), they may be in the wrong proportions. Imagine starting at the point corresponding to (0,1/2) on the (r,g) chromaticity diagram (looks more like cyan because there's not enough red). If you just turn up both knobs in concert, a ray will extend into 3d RGB space with the same color. In other words, color (chromaticity) is *perpendicular* to brightness (luminosity). Imagine a laser pointer, which is a single lambda. It's very bright, but it may just be red. You do *not* want to crank it up and look to see if it's white.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This question should help. [What is Gray, from a physics POV?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/339130/37364) In particular, see the graph (copied here) in my answer that shows how sensitive each kind of color receptor is to various wavelengths of light.

[image: Graph of color receptor sensitivities to various wavelengths of light]

A color is your response to a mix of wavelengths. Most light has many wavelengths, and stimulates all kinds to some degree. If light has more short wavelengths than long, the blue receptors will be most stimulated, and the light will be seen as blue.

If you see a mix that stimulates each kind equally, you see white if the light is bright. Dimmer light may appear gray or black.

The graph shows how much a monochromatic light like a laser stimulates receptors. All wavelengths stimulate more than one kind of receptor.

A monochromatic blue light at 425 nm stimulates blue much more than other receptors. A yellowish light around 555 nm stimulates the red and green receptors equally. With the right mix, you can make white from those two colors.

Your example is slightly more complicated. It too can be made to produce white.
490 is right around where blue and green are equally stimulated. Red is also to a lesser degree. If you add the right amount of light at  690 nm, you can stimulate the red receptors without adding much green. You can make them equally stimulated.

Comment: You are implicitly assuming that you're not overloading the retinal cones here

Comment: What does that mean? Is that like a CCD that can only count so many photons in a given amount of time?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft - Question for you

Answer (score 37):

**Yes, but not with equal amounts of each.**

In order to answer this, we need to understand the [CIE 1931 color space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIE_1931_color_space), and think about its algebraic properties.

Essentially what the CIE specification says is that, while light comes to us as a spectrum filled with varying amounts of photons in the wavelength range 380-700nm, our *eyes* are engineered in such a way that they only have 3 receptors.

These rod and cone receptors act linearly on the frequency/wavelength distribution, and can be represented as 3 integrals of "color matching functions" against the distribution (linear functionals). One is sensitive *mostly* in the "red" region ($\approx$ 500-700nm), one in the "green" ($\approx$ 440-660nm, more spread, smaller peak), and one in the "blue" ($\approx$ 380-500nm).

The **color matching functions** are determined *empirically*, meaning by experiment. They got a bunch of people in a room, and gave them 3 light sources at approximately *pure* wavelengths (single wavelength for red, green, and blue). They asked them, given some "color" (light of a single wavelength along the visible spectrum), to adjust their 3 knobs until *they perceived* the color to match. As the wavelength to match is adjusted in many discrete increments, we get 3 RGB values for each participant. We can then take an average to get 3 fairly smooth curves.

[image: color matching functions]

Some (in this case, just red) knobs might need to be "negative". Since "amount of light" should be positive, we do this the same way we construct the integers - as pairs of positive numbers (their difference is the integer we're secretly representing). In other words, we *add* some, in this case red, light to the light we're trying to match until we can get a match with the remaining two.

The three color matching functions can be viewed as a *line segment* in 3 dimensional RGB space, parameterized by 380-700nm. To avoid negative values, we can **choose** a linear transformation (a 3x3 matrix) to map everything to the positive octant of "XYZ" space, which defines it. There's a fairly canonical one which brings RGB to unit vectors.

One of the directions will correspond to *luminosity*, or how bright the color is. The other two directions encode the *chromaticity*, or what we think of as a "color". To get the chromaticity, we essentially project onto the plane $R+G+B=1$. When we take convex combinations of points on the spectral line (the 380-700nm line segment of wavelengths we know we can represent with our RGBs), we fill in a 2d shape called the *gamut*, which looks a bit like a painter's palette.

[image: gamut]

Your question is essentially asking if white light (the centroid of the gamut) is along a line connecting two points, where one is in the subinterval "cyan" (490-520nm, though looks more like 490-500nm) and the other is in the subinterval "red" (630-700nm).

[image: cyan_plus_red]

It looks like you can indeed add cyan and red to get white, but you need a bit more cyan than red.

One should be careful with notation for mixing colors. There are [additive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_color) and [subtractive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtractive_color) ways of thinking about mixing colors.

Further, the intuitive use of the "+" symbol is a bit misleading. On the chromaticity diagram (or a 2d projection), when we mix colors we are generally taking an *average* (possibly weighted) . This operation is indeed commutative, and it is **idempotent** (red $\oplus$ red = red). However, it is *not* associative (I notice OP did put parentheses).

To get **associativity**, you have to include the luminosity, and use standard addition in 3d RGB space, which is commutative and associative but *not* idempotent.

If you want idempotency, commutativity, *and* associativity then the most general algebra (a free semi-lattice) on 3 discrete generators you can write down $\langle R,G,B \rangle$ turns out to have exactly 7 elements. The price you pay is invertibility. It is a Boolean algebra without the identity, which can be put in one-to-one correspondence with the Fano plane if you want. However, this algebra is not so mysterious. It's just the union (or intersection) algebra:

[image: intersection_colors]

You can [try mixing colors](https://trycolors.com/) to play around (paint is also fun). The closest I could get to grey with this tool by mixing cyan and red was more a Payne's grey, a greyish blue: #7b7b84

Comment: So much discussion of the CIE 1931 color space and not a single mentioning that white is not a point on the chromaticity diagram, but a fuzzy shape that at least includes the Planckian and daylight loci.

Comment: What do you mean by Planckian and daylight loci? I agree, white is just a word.

Comment: See [Planckian locus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planckian_locus) and the 4th figure of [this section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_illuminant#Illuminant_series_D).

Comment: Why do we need the color temperature corresponding to a blackbody to answer OP’s question?

Comment: We just need to take into account that white is a _large_ locus, not even close to a point.

Comment: What do you mean when you say locus? A set of points? I didn’t exclude that possibility. The Planckian locus is an entire line segment on that diagram which contains many colors outside of ‘white’. When someone says white light, it’s a bit easier to take the central point, and just allow that there is a small area around it (say a circle of radius 1nm) that would qualify (my straight line may not go exactly through the centroid, but that’s okay. What’s your definition of white as a set in that diagram?

Comment: White is a fuzzy concept. A blackbody of 2700 K (e.g. 60 W tungsten bulb) is white. Daylight with CCT 65000 K is white. Note how far these points are on the chromaticity diagram.

Comment: True, important to point out that ‘white’ is fuzzy, but it doesn’t take up the *entire* diagram, so we have to use more words, and choose *some* boundary such that inside is ‘white’ and outside is ‘not white’, otherwise we’ll just keep talking.

Comment: My point is that your answer discusses the CIE 1931 color space, the way the color matching functions were defined, the meaning of their negative values, and then simply talk of white point as if it's the unique universal point. An explicit conscious choice should be made here. E.g. if you're talking of the sRGB primaries, then it's natural to use D65 as the white point. For CIE RGB the natural choice is the constant energy white point $E=(x=1/3,y=1/3)$. The latter is the point you implicitly use, but neither the reader, nor (I presume, until now) you know what this point actually is.

Comment: What's your definition of white?

Comment: White is the color defined by an explicit choice of a white point for a color space. It totally depends on the color space and the conditions it's used in.

Comment: That's not a definition. I'll propose one, then. To answer this specific question of interest about the natural world, we choose a *mathematical model*, which we can write down using symbols. In this model, the color 'white' is the set of points of distance <= .1 from the equal energy point $E$ in the chromaticity diagram, the point with coordinates $x=1/3$, $y=1/3$.

Comment: You may use whatever definition you like, just be sure to be explicit about it, because there's no universally agreed upon one.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can. **For a certain meaning of "white".**

It will be white in a sense that is not distinguishable (by healthy unaided eyes) from the white color of daylight or (depending on the actual mix you created) possibly some other white (of different color temperature) illumination source.

Then again, if you use to illuminate some colored objects, such "white" light will have a horribly **bad color rendering**, e.g. some green or violet object may look black because your light lacks the wavelengths this object is able to reflect.

For the same reason, it may not be perceived as white by a lot of (even mildly) color-blind people that don't have problems with the "normal" white.