# Is there any proof we all see same?

Tags: optics, visible-light, perception

Today me and my friend was sitting. He was wearing sunglasses (different from the normal specs). Then a think came in my mind that after wearing the sunglasses we see different colour for a same thing. So, without sunglasses do we see the colour same for a same object. Might be the colour pink for me see me pink and you call pink a different colour, when I see from your eyes?

Comment: Colour perception is relative anyway.

Comment: How do you know?

Comment: Wittgenstein (https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/wittgenstein/) wrote about this. The question is more philosophical than physics.

Comment: It is common knowledge which you can look up. And because when I look at various Stack Exchange threads with different background, the colour I *perceive* depends on the background of the previous page. Anway, after I have been lying on one side for a little while, the scene is greener in the upper eye and redder in the lower eye. So they can't *both* be the same colour that another person sees when upright.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a question about physics.

Comment: Oh! That turned philosophically, I thought the answer would be in physics. So, should I delete from here?

Comment: And, some people cannot perceive some colours at all. This isn't philosophy. A philosophical answer might be that some people perceive the world through rose-tinted spectacles.

Comment: Any experienced photographer knows that the colors he sees in a scene are different from what the camera sees, and that, furthermore, the differences depend on the scene. So, even for a single person, color perception varies!

Comment: [The Retinex Theory of Color Vision](https://www.cnbc.cmu.edu/~tai/cp_papers/E.Land_Retinex_Theory_ScientifcAmerican.pdf) and many other related articles on the Internet.

Comment: Of course your visual perceptions are not the same as mine; they take place in different brains with lots of structural differences.  If you are asking whether those perceptions are *similar* in some important way, then you need to be a lot more specific about what kind of similarity you're asking about.

Comment: A physically relevant corollary is, if perceptions are not all quite the same, how did they decide that 540 THz is the peak of the human eye luminosity function? Averaged a lot of data from different people? It's an interesting question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question is philosophical. There is no way we can know. Never the less, one can say a little bit about it.

We don't all see the same. At least some of us see colors differently.

Most people have 3 types of color receptor. For them, there are 3 primary colors. Other colors are a mix of those. That doesn't tell the full story.

There is red and dark red. Blue and dark blue. And so forth. But there is yellow and brown. There is no dark yellow. Somehow we perceive that as a separate color.

Some people are color blind. They only have two types of receptor. In the most common form, red and green are the same color. You might think the brain is set up to experience 3 types of color, but they only get 2. But...

Under the right circumstances, ordinary people can see colors beyond the usual. Each type of color receptor is stimulated by a range of colors. The ranges overlap. It turns out that every wavelength stimulates more than one receptor. See [What is Gray, from a physics POV?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/339130/37364). So no matter what light you look at, the color you see is the result of more than one receptor.

It is possible to stimulate a receptor with a probe. (Don't try this at home.) When this is done, people report seeing a color they have never seen before.

It is rare, but some people have a 4th type of color receptor. I expect those people see 4 primary colors.

I believe certain types of shrimp have 8 color receptors and 2 polarization receptors. They must see quite a few more colors than we do.

I have no idea what limits how many colors we could see, given the right input device.

Edit: Found a link in [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/626551/37364) to [Mantis shrimp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mantis_shrimp#Eyes)