# Reflection of radiation in atoms

Tags: electronic-band-theory

I want to ask how does an atom reflect an incident radiation shown onto itself?
I understand that when radiation is incident on an atom, the electrons can be excited to higher energy levels shells.
When they talk about reflection, are they referring to the emission of radiation when the electron de-excites?

When light is incident on glass, do the free electrons in the glass experience an oscillating force equivalent tot he frequency of the incident light?
Or is it the oscillation of electons in the same energy band?
Or do they electrons actually excite and de-excite and releasing the same wavelength of radiation?

[image]

Comment: Light doesn't reflect from a single atom, but it can *scatter*. Reflection is just coherent scattering from many atoms :) . So your question first of all should be, why does light scatter from an atom?

Comment: [If we repeatedly divide a colorful solid in half, at what point will the color disappear?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/634760/37364)