# What is black green color? What mean "brightness" in physics?

Tags: visible-light, photons, wavelength

I want to know, what's the difference between green and dark green physically?

I know the darkness of color depends the brightness of context, but if the brightness of context is fixed, and I change only brightness like on photoshop:

[image]

nothing changes around, so what is "brightness" in physic? its the same wavelength (green here), but when it's dark it means there are fewer photons? or what?

Comment: This may help [What is Gray, from a physics POV?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/339130/37364)

Answer (score 1):

Brightness is the relative number of photons emitted. The more photons the brighter the object. Too tell the difference in green and dark green look at you RGB values for the two colors. Green should have rgb values of 0, 255,0. R and B can have small values as other shades of green are probably indistinguishable. Dark green will have a value like 0,100,0. The total brightness will be less. See the images below.  Notice the RGB values for each color.

Green

[image]

And dark green

[image]

Comment: Just as reminder for the OP, this is about spectral colors, and it answers the question. But   there is also color perception https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_vision