# Do all physical processes necessarily imply a computation is taking place?

Tags: universe, simulations, models, laws-of-physics, computer

I would like to understand if any and all physical processes taking place, necessarily imply computations are also taking place.

As a motivating scenario for the question, consider the following:

Around some distant star in a some faraway godforsaken galaxy, exists a boring gas cloud. Here, two protons careen towards each other on an inevitable collision course. The protons' repel each other, and their trajectories inevitably change and off they go.

Has a computation taken place?

Comment: How do you define computation?

Comment: @Jakob is the definition ambiguous?

Comment: It is not certain that computation takes place. However, if you do consider it to be a process, then gravitating bodies interrupt said processes (time dilation). It's like process interruption, in computer science. The shorter the gap, the more the processes are interrupted.

Comment: Unless you restrict what computation represents, in your mind, the question belongs to the philosophy SE…

Comment: Please don't delete and re-ask closed questions.

Comment: I'm closing this because it's unclear what you're asking without a clear definition of what you mean by "computation."

Comment: @Chris The old question said "make the question more objective, or delete it and ask a new one", so that's what I did. It's also unclear what you mean by "computation" being ambiguous. If the answer "depends on your definition of computation", then that's an answer and you should probably post it instead of closing a valid question.

Comment: Well, 'depends on your definition' could be an answer to almost every question...

Answer (score 4):

No, not according to any definition of computation you will find in a well known dictionary. One might compute the trajectory of the two protons, but the protons themselves perform no calculation- they simply respond to forces.

Comment: Are you equivocating calculation with computation?

Comment: Did you mean 'equating'?

Comment: I based my answer on the definitions of computation to be found in well-known dictionaries. Which dictionary definition did you have in mind when you posed your question?

Comment: This definition includes non-arithmetic cases. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computation). When you ask "which definition" is used, do you mean to imply there are multiple valid definitions of computation?

Comment: also: this paper (the end of it) talks about the universe simply computing by virtue of information processing solely. (https://iopscience.iop.org/book/978-1-6817-4093-5/chapter/bk978-1-6817-4093-5ch1)

Comment: There are multiple definitions of virtually every word in English- see a dictionary. The use of the word 'computation' in the sense to which you alludes an obscure one- you will not yet find any mainstream dictionary in which the definitions of computation will include one relating to the motion of particles other, possibly, than in devices used or constructed for computational purposes.

Comment: not alluding - asking.

Answer (score 4):

The universe is real. it contains things like rocks.

Physics exists only in the mind. It contains things like mathematics. Physics is a model of the universe. You can do calculations to predict the outcome of an experiment or something else going on in the universe. This is why calculations are useful.

The universe itself plays out without calculations. (Unless you want to count how a computer or brain plays out.) There is no calculation in the trajectory of a rock. The trajectory just happens as a response to forces.

Comment: Are you then suggesting that there can be no computation without an agent explicitly trying to compute?

Comment: Indeed, electrons are not idiot-savants at solving Schrodinger's equations. They just do what comes naturally.

Comment: @JonCuster Are you saying then that a digital computer running an algorithm without any agents involved is not computing?

Comment: I would say computation requires something doing the computing. I would say that computation is doing a series of operations whose output is a number. Electrons repelling each other is not what I think of as a computation. A simple computation might be allowing an electron to move alongside a ruler and reading the position at some time. But without reading, it is not a computation.

Comment: @mmesser314 I can agree with that, but this seemingly just pushes the onus further down: What state of matter needs to be put together, such that this state of matter can now do the "reading", and hence we can now talk about a computation occurring?

Comment: Whatever state of matter you or someone else interprets as describing a number. I think we are getting farther from physics and into semantics. Concepts like number are in the mind. For more like this on a different topic, see [What is Gray, from a physics POV?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/339130/37364)